# CakePHP form fields containing deep association not working until find()

Tags: forms, cakephp, model, associations

I'm writing my first Cake app and trying to set up my first deep association. It's very nearly working but I have a couple of small issues.

So I created a form to add a customer. A customer has many addresses and an address has many contacts. The issue I have is that the Form helper doesn't seem to recognise the contact fields for formatting purposes. However, if I perform a find() in the action the form displays correctly. It's like the model isn't linking until it's used.

```
Here's the 3 models:

class Customer extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = 'CustomerAddress';
}

class CustomerAddress extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = 'Customer';
    public $hasMany = 'CustomerContact';
}

class CustomerContact extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = 'CustomerAddress';
}
```

Until it's submitted, the add action basically does nothing so I won't bother posting that, but here's some extracts from the view:

```
add.ctp

echo $this->Form->input('CustomerAddress.0.CustomerContact.title', 'options' => array( 'Mr' => 'Mr', 'Miss' => 'Miss', 'Mrs' => 'Mrs', 'Ms' => 'Ms', 'Dr' => 'Dr')))."\n";
echo $this->Form->input('CustomerAddress.0.CustomerContact.first')."\n";
echo $this->Form->input('CustomerAddress.0.CustomerContact.last')."\n";
.....

echo $this->Form->input('CustomerAddress.address1')."\n";
echo $this->Form->input('CustomerAddress.address2')."\n";
.....

echo $this->Form->input('type', array( 'label' => 'Business Customer?'))."\n";
```

So, the CustomerAddress fields work fine, they are the right type, limited length etc to match the database, but the CustomerContact fields aren't working at all. Likewise, if I submit invalid data, the add action does a saveAll and fails, but the form fields are then displayed correctly.

If I add a find() to the action before the page is displayed, they work fine. It's like the Model isn't being included until it's used.

I'm sure there's probably a simple command to get it to read the models or something but I'm a bit stuck with it.

Comment: $belongsTo, $hasMany must be arrays, not strings.

Comment: Nope, strings are fine for single relationships, a recursive find works ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, after much digging, I got this to work by calling `->loadModel` on the controller. Since in this case I need all 3 models loaded in virtually every case, I added a `beforeFilter` to do this every time.

I didn't change the code for any models, but added this to the controller:

```
CustomerController.php 

class CustomerController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array( 'Html', 'Form', 'Humanize');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        // Load associated models
        $this->loadModel( 'CustomerAddress');
        $this->loadModel( 'CustomerContact');
    }

    .....
}
```

Even though the CustomerContact model is loaded from the Customer model instead of the CustomerAddress model, Cake seems to respect the relationship and load it under CustomerAddress. At first, I tried:

```
$this->CustomerAddress->loadModel( 'CustomerContact');
```

but it was failing. Seems to work fine this way.